# C# Copy an object from a list of objects and paste in another location within the list

Tags: c#, list, object, copy, paste

I have a class animal, and have made a list of this class.

```
List<Animal> animalLibrary = new List<Animal>();
```

I'm looking to copy and paste an object from this list, and place it in another location within the list. So, I'd want to make a copy of animalLibrary[c] for example, and paste this object into another location within animalLibrary[].

Using this to copy, seems to work.

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(animalLibrary[c]);
```

Using this to paste, but keeps displaying the msgbox instead.

```
IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
if (iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Serializable))
{
    animalLibrary.Insert(c, (Animal)iData.GetData("Animal"));
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Could not paste the data");
}
Get_Data();
Load_Data();
```

Getting a NullReferenceException from display the data when I force the Insert.

Edit:
Took mammago's advice and created a copy of the Animal class and pasted it using animalLibrary.Insert(index+1, a) 'a' being the copy of animal.

Comment: The ClipBoard class represents the actual _System ClipBoard_. It has nothing to do with copying objects in your code. In your case you might want to simply create a new Animal object and add that one to your list. Alternatively you can let Animal implement the `ICloneable` interface which allows you to create copies of objects by using the `Clone()`method.

Comment: I suggest running it under the debugger.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to use the Clipboard here, but to put an object on the cb, it needs to be serializable.

Comment: Is your Animal class marked as Serializable? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx

Comment: I would not use the clipboard for this task (or any other task within one application).

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can move an item from a list to another "location" in the same list :

```
var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3};

// get the object from the list
var value = list[0];
// insert it at the end of the list.
list.Insert(3, value);
// list is now { 1, 2, 3, 1} ]
```

Comment: No where in the original question does it say anything about _moving_. OP wants to _copy_ the object and insert the copy into the list.